# How can I remove black bars at smaller resolutions?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, resolution, monitor

I have an HP Pavilion dv1000 laptop with a widescreen monitor.

My monitor works well at its native resolution, But when I choose 1024x768, I see black bars on left and right side of the monitor.

I used a live-cd of an old Backtrack 3 distro, and I notice it can stretch the image there, but in Ubuntu I can't. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xrandr --ouput [name_output] --set "scaling mode" Full`.
This way the image will scale to the full size of the screen, of course you have to do this every time you want to solve the problem or modify permanently your options.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really answer the question, but please take into account that LCD displays are meant to be used in the native resolution. If you don't want to do that, at least choose resolutions with the same aspect ratio (for WXGA this is 5:3). In theory it might be possible to stretch 1024x768 into 1280x768, covering the black bars, but the resulting quality would be horrible.